# OpenCV Assertion failed error

Tags: javascript, node.js, opencv

I am working on a project which requires face recognition and prediction. When I upload an image, it should recognize the person from the database.I am trying to implement using Nodejs and OpenCV.
My code looks like this:

```
var FaceRecognizer = new cv.FaceRecognizer();
var uploadDir = joinPath(__dirname, "/images");
var fileDir = joinPath(__dirname, "/uploads");
var cvImages = [];


fs.readdir(uploadDir, function(err, files){
if(err){
    throw new Error(err);

}
if(files.length > 0){ //There are some user related image folders
    files.forEach(function(subfolder, index, array){
        if(subfolder != ".DS_Store" ){ //Issue with Mac, test on Linux-VM
            //We are now iterating over each subfolder
            var subFolderDir = joinPath(uploadDir, "/"+"subfolder");
            var images = fs.readdirSync(subFolderDir);
            images.forEach(function(image, index, array){//Get Matrix Objekt for each image to train OpenCV
                if(image != ".DS_Store"){
                    var imageDir = joinPath(subFolderDir, "/"+image);

                    cv.readImage(imageDir, function(err, im){
                        var channels = im.channels();
                        if(channels >=3){

                            var labelNumber = parseInt(Math.floor((Math.random()* 10)+1)); //Create labelnumber; Account-Id starts by 1, labels for openCV start with 0
                            cvImages.push(new Array(labelNumber,im));  //Add image to Array
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
    if(cvImages.length > 3){
        console.log("Training images (we have at least 3 images)", cvImages);
        FaceRecognizer.trainSync(cvImages);
        cv.readImage(fileDir, function(err, im){

            if(err) res.send(err);
            var whoisit = FaceRecognizer.predictSync(im);
            console.log("Identified image", whoisit);
        })
    }else{
        console.log("Not enough images uploaded yet", cvImages);
    }
}else{
    console.log("There are no images uploaded yet!");
}
});
```

I am getting this error:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (s >= 0) in setSize, file /build/opencv-SviWsf/opencv-2.4.9.1+dfsg/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 116
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /build/opencv-SviWsf/opencv-2.4.9.1+dfsg/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp:116: error: (-215) s >= 0 in function setSize

Aborted (core dumped)
```

Can anyone suggest any possible solution?